# Azure Pipeline for ASP.NET Webforms WebSite

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops

I have a legacy app on ASP.NET Webforms Website. The solution is build in Azure Pipeline good so far, but it is ignoring the properties for msbuild task, actually, this is my yaml file for VSBuild task:

```
    - task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build PowerDetails Web Forms
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:EnableUpdateable=true /p:DebugSymbols=true /p:WDPMergeOption=DonotMerge /p:DeleteExistingFiles=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    maximumCpuCount: true
    vsVersion: 'latest'
```

And then this is generating **.compiled** files for each aspx file in my articraft/bin folder.

I do not want to get .compiled files in my bin folder, I want to get only dll of the project in the bin folder.

it seems like the task is ignoring the properties "/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:EnableUpdateable=true".

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my fix:

I have a legacy app on ASP.NET Webforms **Website** Project (not WebApp). And this is the setting for Azure Pipeline and the change you have to do in your solutions:

YAML File:

```
    trigger:
- master

name: $(rev:r)-$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)_$(Hours)$(Minutes)$(Seconds)_B-$(BuildID)

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install Nuget'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Nuget Command'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build PowerDetails Web Forms
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:ExcludeApp_Data=True /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=True /p:EnableUpdateable=True /p:DebugSymbols=True /p:WDPMergeOption="DonotMerge" /p:WebPublishMethod="FileSystem" /p:PublishProvider="FileSystem" /p:DeleteExistingFiles="True" /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    maximumCpuCount: true
    vsVersion: 'latest'
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: Publish Pipeline Artifact
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'WinForm_Artifacts'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Now you have to update the SLN file and replace this settings for WebSite project:

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "WebSite1", "http://localhost:8080", "{BF5B70E3-DC4C-4AE4-BCD8-D0B5D3A6AA66}"
ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
    SccProjectName = "SAK"
    SccAuxPath = "SAK"
    SccLocalPath = "SAK"
    SccProvider = "SAK"
    UseIISExpress = "true"
    TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1"
    ProjectReferences = "{ba89722c-1b24-4da4-b963-0df5cf17af21}|PowerDetail.Web.dll;"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Clean = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Force = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/drop"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "WebSite\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "..\..\temp\drop\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Clean = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Force = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/drop"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "WebSite\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "..\..\temp\drop\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "true"


    SlnRelativePath = "WebSite\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

And the pipelie will generate this artifact:

[artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0awvF.png)

this is all!

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to get .compiled files in my bin folder, I want to get only dll of the project in the bin folder.

According to the document [File Handling During ASP.NET Precompilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/e22s60h9(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> For executable files in an ASP.NET Web application, the compiler
> assemblies and files with the .compiled file name extension. The
> assembly name is generated by the compiler. The .compiled file does
> not contain executable code. Instead, it contains only the information
> that ASP.NET needs to find the appropriate assembly.
>
> After the precompiled application is deployed, ASP.NET uses the
> assemblies in the Bin folder to process requests. The precompilation
> output includes .aspx or .asmx files as placeholders for pages. The
> placeholder files contain no code. They exist only to provide a way to
> invoke ASP.NET for a specific page request and so that file
> permissions can be set to restrict access to the pages.

So, we will have to **disable the pre-compile steps** to remove them. **You just need to change the properties `/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true` to `/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=false`**.

Comment: Thank you, but I did that change, and this is still generating .compiled files in the \bin folder.

Comment: @CarlosDev, Please share how did you get the bin folder, just the task like publish build artifact and where you check the bin folder?

Comment: Hi Leo, this is my build task:

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Azure-Pipele-Profile.pubxml' #'/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

Comment: @CarlosDev, Thanks for your reply. But I could not see you add the argument `/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true` in your msbuildArgs and I want to know how did you find the .compiled files still in the \bin folder? In other words, where you to check this .compiled files, from artifact? And how about the result when you use above msbuild arguments to build the project in your local?

Comment: Hi Leo, I have a task to publish the artifact:
_- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: Publish Pipeline Artifact
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'WinForm_Artifacts'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'_

Comment: Leo, and the .compiled files are in "WinForm_Artifacts/temp/Published/bin" this is the artifact generated by task that I told you above.

Comment: @CarlosDev, You have set MSBuild arguments `/p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, so you do not need to add the task PublishPipelineArtifact to re-publish the artifact. And Have you add the arguments `/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true`? And have to test this argument without azure devops, in you local?